# Is improving the ability to read on-topic on Writers?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition, specific-question

We have a question about [improving the concentration while reading](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/1448/what-can-i-do-to-improve-my-concentration-when-reading). I wanted to vote to close as being off-topic, but then resisted.

You cannot write without reading, which leads to the question: if you can improve your reading, does this also improve your writing? If you learn to be more concentrated when reading, are you more concentrated when writing, too?

Allowing questions about reading could lead to topics like *faster reading*, *eye-gentle/friendly reading* (there are whole books about this topics; with exercises for the eye muscles).

I can live with the existing question, but I really do not want to read posts about fast reading and stuff.

Comment: definitely off topic

Comment: Seeing no votes for on-topic, I added mine to the close votes and the question is now closed.

Comment: Totally fair and I accept the outcome (ironically I also got some great answers, so seems like everyone is winning).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Personally, I think it's off-topic, because the question doesn't ask anything about writing. The OP isn't even starting off with (for instance), "As a writer, …"

The question may be *vaguely* related to writing, but only in the same way that game playing is related to game development. Questions about the former are off-topic on the latter site, and vice versa.

If a question isn't writing-related, it's off-topic here (imo).

Comment: I agree. He was asking for reading advice, not advice on how or what to read to become a better writer. Seems off-topic for a writing group.

Comment: Game playing and development is a good comparison. That shows that it is off-topic.

Comment: I now feel challenged to come up with a reading question that *is* writing-related, somehow. :)